# How to fix an error zip argument #1 Must support iteration?

Tags: python, syntax

I'm trying to find a solution to my issue. 
My code :

```
Expected_str = "test"
def get_individual_fitness(individual):
    fitness = 0 
    for c, expected_c in zip(individual, Expected_str):
        if c == expected_c:
            fitness += 1
    return fitness
```

I get : "for c, expected_c in zip(individual, Expected_str):
TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration"

Comment: As the error message says, `individual` has to be an iterable.

Comment: It is an iterable...

Comment: We'll never know since you are not showing us what it is.

Comment: What's the type of the `individual`?

Comment: individual is a list.

Comment: _individual is a list._ I just ran the code with a test list, it works fine.

Comment: Not for me. But this is just a bite of code. I can't write more about my code.

Comment: Can you give an example of how `individual` is constructed?

Comment: individual is constructed from a list of string.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your individual list.

Your code runs fine with an iterable list as shown below.

Input

```
individual = ['t','e','s','t']
get_individual_fitness(individual)
```

Output

```
4
```